# Extract string using regex trouble with ending

Tags: regex, powershell

Attempting to extract the status value from the below string ($data) using regex. The trouble is specifying the end of the value.

```
$data = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><bi:Element xml:bi="http://www.bi.com/1.0.0" status="www.google.com/path/file.ext" version="2.0" xml:pa="http://www.pa.com/1.1.1" ...>

// Attempt #1
$data -match "status='"(.*)'""
// $matches[1] contains www.google.com/path/file.ext" version="2.0" xml:pa="http://www.pa.com/1.1.1" ...>

// Attempt #2
$data -match "status='"(.*)'" "
// $matches[1] contains www.google.com/path/file.ext" version="2.0" xml:pa="http://www.pa.com/1.1.1" ...>

// Attempt #3
$data -match "status='"(.*)'" v"
// $matches[1] contains www.google.com/path/file.ext
```

Why does not the first attempt work? I do not really want to use the third and working example because it relies on order of attribute. What is a better solution?

Comment: Use `([^"]+)` or `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)` or, even better, use an XML parser

Comment: are you sure you want to do this via regex instead of parsing the xml?

Comment: acro444: Your first example caused a syntax due to the double quote, not sure how to escape it. The second example work but do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

The first one doesn't work because the matching in regexp is **greedy**.

This means that it will try to consume as much as possible from the input and if a match is not reached by the time it reaches the end of the input it will back track and try another match, until it:

- either find a match or
- backtracks at the start of the attempted match (this is not necessarily the beginning of the input) and then it fails.

The first and second regexps do pretty much the same, eat up as much of the input as possible, matching the **last** inverted commas or the last inverted commas and space.

The third one on the other hand needs to match `" v` for it to work and I'm guessing that in your string that's the right most place where it matches.

Note: I agree with the comments that you should be using an xml parser for this, if the pattern that you're looking for is simple, think about using split instead of regexp

Comment: Yes, it appears the regexp is greedy. Expected the '" (single followed by double quote) on both sides of the parentheses to indicate start and stop. Still do not understand why this does not work?

Comment: I don't know of any regexp flavor that does that :)

Comment: It was an attempt to say I want everything between the double quotes. Maybe using single and then double quote is incorrect way of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Try matching non-quotes:

```
$data -match "status='"[^']*""
```

Comment: This causes a syntax error in PowerShell ISE due to double quote at the end. Not sure how to escape it, tried \" and '" but neither worked.